# Indicate Heating, Burning and so on in Circuit Simulation Software

Tags: simulation, software

Is there have any simulation software which is indicating other than current signals like heating, burning and so on with time by **Power**. Circuit simulating like real world behaviors of circuit.

- Component Heating or buring
- Wire or Track Heating or burring

Have this feature in Proteus or Multisim software?

Comment: A software that shows that kind of information is very similar to riding a bike with support wheel.

Comment: if it is not shows in software, we don't know whether it wants support wheel or not. All should want to simulate before the production.

Comment: @HarrySvensson, sometimes you want to get over the fuss of calculating power dissipation of some components and let the software do the labor.

Comment: @HarrySvensson I dissagree. Thermal simulation is a big part when you are dealing with high power or high density circuits, and there are very complex and large packages to do that.

Comment: Micro-cap in "dynamic DC" mode puts warnings on the schematic (as well as DC current, power and voltage levels) telling you if something will get hot. It's a bit babyish but the dynamic DC function is so useful I forgive it and you can tell it not to display any of the above. Student version is free and is really very good. Beats the hell out of crappy LTSpice.

Answer (score 1):

In Multisim, you can use the "**Rated**" components to simulated thermal overheating. All the components available in this set have thermal simulations. You can adjust the thermal parameters in the component's properties.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem with simulating this is that the temperature rise depends on the physical shape and size of the system. This is information that is not included in your general circuit simulation. Take for example the following schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSj3W6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Imagine the first schematic is of a system where the resistors are next to each other and in the second case the resistors are far apart. To your software, these schematics are identical. It doesn't know how close these resistors are, how they are cooled, etc. All of this matters a lot for actual values of temperature.

There are options in different tools to add some information about this, as shown in Abdullah Baig's answer to this question. However, these will at best give you a rough indication. If you are in an enclosure with no airflow, you might find your temperatures get a lot higher than if that same component was in free space. Not to mention that if you have more than one component getting hot, you need to really include the influence on each other to get accurate results.

There does exist software that can do this. With some, it is in the form of a seperate tool, where you would use the information you get from your spice simulation to determine the components generating the most heat and then tell the software that part of the model gets hot. An example of this would be Autodesk CFD. See the image below, where a component was connected to a metal wall. This was the only component that got hot. The power dissapated inside the component was then set. The simulation software could then determine the steady state temperatures and airflow.

[image]

There are also more complex multiphysics simulation software, such as the software provided by Ansys or COMSOL. However, this is not a simple tool to use; they are very expensive packages and full simulations take a good while to set up, and if done wrong the results are worthless.

Comment: Thank you for answer. How to use Fusion 360 to get above image?

Comment: I don't know if fusion 360 can do that. This package is Autodesk CFD, which is a separate (and expensive) piece of software.

Answer (score 0):

Hotspot or temp. rise is a product of thermal conductance or resistance ['C/W] times the V(t)*I(t)=Pd power dissipation in real-time. The conductor radiator area and restriction of convection air-flow or inclusion of high-velocity air-flow and PCB copper area for SMT parts are strong design factors.

This requires you to enter the thermal properties into the design and the air mass, speed and direction. Thus generally it is not worth the effort to model this. Instead a 1st order T_rise=Pd*Rja calculation is done for each suspect hot part and then verified during Design Validation Testing , DVT.

If you wish to see PD in real-time, may programs can do that part then use your own validated Rule-of-Thumb such as 10mm^2/W for a 60'C rise for open convection cooled conductors.

[image]

See the 4k resistor power dissipation Pd(t) graph and red colour-coded Power dissipation which has a slider you can adjust on Falstad's simulator.